# Model binding difficulty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am having a model and I am using ajax.post.  I can see that the model binding isn`t being done for the arraylists in my model, though binding done for the properties of int or string type. Why is that so? My code is as below.

I have a model with the following properties

```
public class ProjectModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public ArrayList Boys= new ArrayList();
```

}

In my view I have

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
     var project = new Object();
      var Boys= new Array();
var ID;
.......
ID = $('#ID').val();
project.Boys= Boys;
```

.....

```
$.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: '<%=Url.Action("Create","Project") %>',
                 data: JSON.stringify(project),
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "html",
                 success: function () {
                 },
                 error: function (request, status, error) {
                                         }
             });
```

//

My controller

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Create(ProjectModel project)
    {
        try
        {
            project.CreateProject();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

....

Comment: `ArrayList` is not generic. What type of objects do you intend to store inside? A generic `List<Boy>` or `Boy[]` would be more appropriate here where you need to define each property of the `Boy` type.

Comment: Can you explain please using an example? I am filling the array in the view and want to have arary model binding.

Actually I can see that the values sent from the views are not binded to the model and the arrays still have the values already instantiated. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The ModelBinding is done using the name.
For any Collection that you want to be bind, it must have this format:

```
project.property1
project.property2
```

and for the Boys Collection

```
project.Boys[0].property1
project.Boys[0].property2

project.Boys[1].property1
project.Boys[1].property2
```

If you are using a form, you can just correctly set the names of the inputs and using jquery:

```
//inside the ajax definition
    data: $('#formID').serialize(),
```

**EDIT:** if Boys doesn't have properties then the name should be:

```
project.Boys[0]
project.Boys[1]
project.Boys[2]
```

Have you tried binding with a second parameter like this?

```
public ActionResult Create(ProjectModel project, string[] Boys)
```

I didn't use `ArratList` because i did some test and it does not seems to bind at all, i prefer to use a normal array declaration.

Another thing you can try is inspect the `FormCollection`

```
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection f)
```

put a breakpoint just at the beginning and inspect the values, if the names inside don't follow the format project.Boys it will never bind.

**EDIT2**: If you want to Bind to multiple arrays then just add a collection definition to the model:

```
public class ProjectModel

    {
        public IEnumerable<string[]> Boys { get; set; }
    }
```

and the names should be:
for the first array:

```
project.Boys[0]
project.Boys[0]
```

for the second:

```
project.Boys[1]
project.Boys[1]
```

.
.
.

But in order to archive this the definition of Boys in Javascript should be a collection of a colecction as well and im not sure how to define that in js.

**PD:** if you are pushing the value manually to the arrays and that values comes from inputs as you state here `Boys.Push($('#tex1').val())` then you should be able to serialize those inputs and save you a lot of troubles =D.
ie: to simulate your situation it ll be something like...

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
       { %>
       <% var i1 = 5; %>
       <% var i2 = 5; %>
       <% for(var i=0; i < i1; i++)
          { %>
          <% for (var ix = 0; ix < i2; ix++)
             {%>
          <input name="boys[<%=i %>]"  value="VALUE_HERE"/>
          <%} %>
       <%} %>
       <input type="submit" value="sumit" />
    <%} %>
```

and doing  `data: $('#formID').serialize()` give the same result as create a `project` js object and then doing `JSON.stringify(project)`.

Comment: Boys is only an arraylist and I am filling the array as Boys.Push($('#tex1').val()) and it doesn not have any property.

Comment: @user Omar is saying you can't use ArrayList w/ model binding. If you simply want a list of strings (which is what it looks like to me), then you could POST a comma separated string and split it server side.

Comment: Thanks Omar, I still have a difficulty.  Actually I have to do model binding of arrays using javascript and the difficult part is that I have 5 - 6 arrays and I don`t know how to proceed.

Comment: OK, i added my solution to the answer, please take a look at the last part i think you are double working when you create a JS object and then doing JSON.stringify.